# vim: replace block

Tags: vim

Let's say I have this text:

```
something "something else"
something here "just another quoted block"
```

I want to substitute "something else" with "just another quoted block", so I do:

```
/quot<enter>   (to jump to second quoted block searching for the string "quot")
yi"            (to yank inner text for current quoted block)
?else<enter>   (to jump back to the first quoted block wich contains "else")
vi"            (to visually select the quoted block)
p              (to paste yanked text)
```

This works, but I would like to know if the two last steps can be replaced by a single one, to avoid visual mode.  I know it's not a huge gain keystroke-wise, but I think that the Vim philosophy would encourage what I'm trying to do, and every time I do this my mind keeps asking for this command.  :-P

What I tried so far:

r  (replace) replaces just one character
c  (change) throws me into Insert mode and does not let me paste the text.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to avoid visual mode? It's actually the fastest in this case scenario.

Comment: You don't have to be precise with `i"` and `a"`: You can do `yi"` and `vi"` from the start of the line and it will act on the first quoted string in the line.

Answer (score 3):

```
"_di"P
```

Delete inside quotes to the blackhole register; paste last yanked before cursor.

Or

```
ci"<Ctrl-R>0<ESC>
```

Change inside quotes to retrieve last yank; leave insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

With my [ReplaceWithRegister plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703), the last two steps would be `gri"`. It also offers `grr` (replace current / [count] lines); though it only saves a little typing, I find this indispensable.

Answer (score 2):

Key stroke wise, `j$yi"k` then `vi"p` is actually probably the fastest. However, if you absolutely must go into insert mode you can `j$yi"k` then `"_ci"<C-r>"` or `ci"<C-r>0`. The `:help i_CTRL-R` operator allows you to put the contents of a register into insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to keep it simple, using what I feel is more intuitive with every day commands:

```
j
yi"
k
ci"
<ESC>
p
```

Comment: This is what I tried before, but the Change command yanks the contents of the quotes I want to replace, and the Paste command pastes the same string that was there before.  Instead of `ci"` I found that I had to use `vi"`